# Diffeomorphic dimensionality reduction

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I was reading the paper about [diffeomorphic dimensionality reduction](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2008/file/647bba344396e7c8170902bcf2e15551-Paper.pdf)

Where the author uses the definition

> Let $U$ and $V$ be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^a$ and $\mathbb{R}^b$, respectively. The mapping $F : U \rightarrow V$ is said to be a diffeomorphism if it is bijective (i.e. one to one), smooth (i.e. belonging to $C^\infty$), and
> has a smooth inverse map $F^{-1}$

Wikipedia seems to use the same definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphism but seems to claim that

> Diffeomorphisms are necessarily between manifolds of the same dimension.

i.e from the definition in the paper then $a = b$ otherwise there is no diffeomorphism. So there can be no diffeomorphic dimensionality reduction. What am I missing here ?

Is there a way to construct a diffeomorphic map that can reduce the dimensionality of a submanifold ?

Comment: Wikipedia is correct here: if $F : U \to V$ is a diffeomorphism, then $\dim U = \dim V$ as manifolds. With that said, I doubt the authors of the paper you linked are talking about diffeomorphically reducing dimension "on the nose". Maybe someone else is more experienced can shed light on exactly what they are trying to do in the paper.

Comment: Wikipedia is almost correct here, they forgot to assume that $U$ (equivalently, $V$) is nonempty.